# How do we feel about adding feature of directed questions?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

How does the community feel about adding a feature to allow directed questions, or in other words, allow OP to request someone respond to their question. I am thinking of a button to be clicked if the person declines to answer when asked. I also active on Quora which has this feature.

Given the userbase is concentrated in technology with  substantial number of developers and others in tech roles, this may be useful. For example I work in cyber security and I know other folks on this site in my industry. (520, rory alsop etc.)

Comment: This is an interesting feature, and would make sense on some other platform. Not StackExchange, IMHO.

Comment: cross-site duplicate: [Asking specific users a question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/188898/165773)

Answer (score 8):

I don't see how this would add anything positive to the site.

If you're enough of a regular to know the users and have one in mind, then you know how to contact them via chat and ask that they take a look at your question.

All this does is dissuade other potential contributors and potentially annoy whoever gets pinged.

Answer (score 8):

> Given the userbase is concentrated in technology with substantial number of developers and others in tech roles, this may be useful.

The questions asked aren't technical ones, so this would have limited use on this site. Outweighing any positives it would make it easier to troll a user, the OP may miss out on insights from users that were not pinged, and many users may not relish getting random requests.

None of us are paid to do this, it's fine while we can choose exactly how and when we contribute. But any even sideways attempt to coerce would not be welcomed by myself at least but probably others as well.